# Error 405: SERVER12345: Error reported: 405

Tags: curl, wsdl

Would like to know what I need to add on my command I encountered error "Error Reported: 405" when I using POST but when I get GET command no error encounter.

Here's my command I use

```
 curl -vv -k --user username:password --header "Authorization: Basic qweasdqweasd123" -H "Content-Type: application/xml" -X POST https://myURL.wsdl
```

Comment: Continue using GET?

Comment: Hi I already figure out the solution I modify my command and also add the my update.xml using -d @myupdate.xml. We can now close this issue.